# Copy files using php function with UI interface... for daily uses

Tags: php, html, function

i have three sites... like

```
a.mydomain.com 
b.mydomain.com 
c.mydomain.com
```

I want to copy some files form `a.mydomain.com/files` to `b.mydomain.com/files` and `c.mydomain.com/files` without removing to original files....

i found some php codes while searching like `copy()`
but want to use some UI based copy function... because i copy the files daily and some times twice in one day...

i actually want to make a stand alone page with two buttons...

`a.mydomain.com to b.mydomain.com`

and

`a.mydomain.com to c.mydomain.com`

so that every time i want to copy files... i just have to open the page and press the desired button to copy files .....

I am new to website development and i don't know much about PHP functions...

tell me some easy to follow solutions .... :)

Comment: So? simply make a UI and attach `copy` to it, since you already know how it works

Comment: i don't know how to make `UI` and how to  attach `copy` to it...

Comment: i just know how to make a simple HTML page...

Comment: Make a page with a form with a button that says "copy" (or whatever you like) and then at the top of the page, write PHP code that will be triggered when a form is submitted and use `copy` there.

Comment: could you please help for the coding i am very beginner in this kind of stuff :)

Comment: or just give some link to follow .... which will guide me through cods.... :)